# Excel file gets corrupted which uploaded from LWC to Azure blob storage

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, blob, azure

I am uploading files from salesforce lwc to azure blob storage using SAS token and the code is below i am using

```
<lightning-input type="file" label="Attachment" onchange={handleFileUploaded} multiple
            accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv, .png, .doc, .docx, .pdf, .jpg, .docx">
</lightning-input>
```

JS

```
 handleFileUploaded(event) {
        console.log('==file==' + event.target.files.size);
        if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
                console.log('==file size==' + event.target.files[i].size);
                const file = event.target.files[i]
                var reader = new FileReader()
                reader.onload = e => {
                    const fileContents = reader.result.split(',')[1]
                    this.filesData.push({
                        'fileName': file.name,
                        'fileContent': fileContents,
                        'filetype': 'Test'
                    });
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
            FileCount = event.target.files.length;
        }
    }
```

Azure JS

```
var requestOptions = {
                method: 'PUT',
                body: this.filebase64,
                crossOrigin: true,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/" + filextensiontype,
                    "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'PUT'
                }
            };

            fetch(storagelink + this.sasToken, requestOptions)
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((responseJson) => {

                    console.log('responseJson ', responseJson)
                })
                .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

**filextensiontype** gives values like xlsx, docx, txt, pdf . I was trying .xlsx file. The file is getting uploaded fine. But when i download , it giving the below eeror

[image]

Any idea what is going wrong. I am thinking the content type is creating some problem .

Comment: have you tried debugging the base64 at the Azure end? Maybe the base64 is appended with special characters. It happened to while moving files from Salesforce to Azure using DataFactory. To resolve that I have to use the Azure function.
You can read more on it - https://medium.com/@mukulmahawariya11/azure-functions-and-conversion-of-base64-encoded-files-of-salesforce-55e675f85d00